# if a requireJS module sets a global on $, how do I execute the module code only when the global has been assigned?

Tags: javascript, jquery, module, requirejs, jqplot

I'm trying to load [jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/) as a requireJS module.

My `main.js` has a path and shim like this:

```
require.config({
  , paths: {
      plot:          '../js/plugins/jqplot/jqplot.module'
  } 
  , shim: {
    'plot':          { deps: ['jquery']}
  }
});
```

Since this module is not needed on most pages, I'm waiting for the **pageXYZ** to be loaded and then inside a `<script></script>`, I'm calling:

```
require(['plot'], 
    function (plot) {
       // do stuff
    }
);
```

And my `jqplot.module` looks like this:

```
define(['../js/plugins/jqplot/jquery.jqplot'],
    function () {
        require([
                '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer'
              , '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.logAxisRenderer'
              , '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer'
              , '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer'
              , '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer'
              , '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels'
              , '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.enhancedLegendRenderer'
        ], 
        function (){
          return $.jqplot;
        }
    );
  }
);
```

which returns the correct object with all sub-plugins defined and usable.

However, my **Do stuff** code runs **BEFORE** `jqplot` is assigned to `$`, so I'm still getting undefined errors when my code runs (I assume, because the files are all loaded, so requirejs starts running)

**Question**:
What can I do halt code execution until the jqplot has been assigned to $?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) I think this line from your question:

```
define(['../js/plugins/jqplot/jquery.jqplot'],
```

should read:

```
define(['../js/plugins/jqplot/jquery.module'],
```

2) You do not need a `shim`, because you have a module definition that loads `jqplot`. So change your `requirejs.config` to

```
require.config({
  , paths: {
      plot:          '../js/plugins/jqplot/jqplot.module'
  } 
});
```

3) your jqplot.module is not returning anything right now. Change it to:

```
define([
      '../js/plugins/jqplot/jquery.jqplot'
    ],
    function () {
        var plot;
        require([
            '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer',
            '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.logAxisRenderer',
            '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer',
            '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer',
            '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer',
            '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels',
            '../js/plugins/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.enhancedLegendRenderer'
            ],
        function () {
            plot = $.jqplot;
        });
        return plot;
    });
```

This is all untested, but I think these should help

Comment: ok. I think I will patch something together with this. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

Answering this question and all the repeats, basic above answer is close but no cigar, as require is async, as such require could/will fire before define closure closes and returns, async safe solution below :

Nasty problem, as it's a chain of three dependencies

jquery is required for jqplot which is required for jqplot plugins, I have a simpler solution based on the same lines as the one above

first do your requirejs "main.js" config like so

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "path/to/jquery-1.10.2.min",

        // WORKAROUND : jQuery plugins + shims
        "jqplot.core": "path/to/jquery-jqplot-1.0.8.min",
        "jqplot": "jquery-jqplot-module-with-plugins-1.0.8"
    },
    shim: {
        "jqplot.core": {deps: ["jquery"]},
        "jqplot": {deps: ["jqplot.core"]}
    }
});
```

create a wrapper file module file called "jquery-jqplot-module-with-plugins-1.0.8.js", containing :

```
// wraps jquery jqplot plugin in define statement
define([
    "jquery",
    "path/to/jqplot.highlighter.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.cursor.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.enhancedLegendRenderer.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.pieRenderer.min",
    "path/to/jqplot.donutRenderer.min",
], function($) {
    var jqplot;
    jqplot = $.jqplot;
    return jqplot;
});
```

Then when ever you need jqplot with those plugins, simply call for "jqplot" which will load "jquery" then "jqplot.core" then all the jqplot modules, then finally return the jqplot object :)

```
require(["jquery", "jqplot"], function ($, $jqplot) {
    console.log("Success..Inside Require JS");
    console.log("Plot...", $.jqplot, $jqplot);
});
```

or

```
define(["jquery", "jqplot"], function ($, $jqplot) {
    console.log("Success..Inside Define JS");
    console.log("Plot...", $.jqplot, $jqplot);
});
```

tada! :)

ps jquery plugins are evil, no suggestion how to fix that situation, just a statement of fact

cheers

Ant

Comment: cheers :)

doing my whole actionscript is dead, currently embracing the new "L'enfant terrible" javascript, so expect more random answers and things in the next few weeks